# MSBuild copy specific files and folders

Tags: php, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Lets say I have the following folder structure

```
app
-->folder1
----->subfolder2
----->subfolder3
-->folder2
----->subfolder4
-->folder3
```

And I want to use the `Copy`task to copy `folder2` (including subfolders) and `subfolder3` to my output.

How can I achieve that? Btw, I'm using MSBuild for a PHP website, and in the real situation there are a lot more subfolders and specific folders I want to copy.

Answer (score 3):

Create an item group with `folder2` and `subfolder3` in it and then use the `copy` task.

For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <sourceFiles Include="app\folder1\subfolder3\**\*.*" />
  <sourceFiles Include="app\folder2\**\*.* />
</ItemGroup>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(sourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="c:\output\%(RecursiveDir)"></Copy>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try RoboCopy:

```
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll" TaskName="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.RoboCopy"/>

<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.RoboCopy 
  Source="$(YourSourcePath)" 
  Destination="$(YourOutputPath)" 
  Files="*.*"
  Options="/MIR"/>
```

The `/MIR` option duplicates the whole folder tree including empty folders

Robocopy reference:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx

[MSBuild extensions pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/)